# How to call oracle stored procedure in Codeigniter

Tags: php, oracle, codeigniter, stored-procedures, procedure

I am new with CI application and oracle database. I want to execute a stored procedure from active record. But I can't get hold of any solid documentation.

Does anyone have any experience with calling stored procs with CodeIgniter and/or Active Record and passing in parameters?

```
function write_message($type = "debug", $message = "", $description = "")
{
    $_fw =& get_instance();

    $data['LOG_TYPE'] = 4;

    switch ($type)
    {
        case "error":
            $data['LOG_TYPE'] = 1;
            break;

        case "success":
            $data['LOG_TYPE'] = 2;
            break;

        case "message":
            $data['LOG_TYPE'] = 3;
            break;

        case "debug":
            $data['LOG_TYPE'] = 4;
            break;

        default:
            $data['LOG_TYPE'] = 1;
            break;
    }

    $data['LOG_URI_STRING'] = uri_string();

    $data['LOG_MESSAGE'] = $message;

    $data['LOG_DESCRIPTION'] = $description;

    $data['LOG_USER_AGENT'] = $_fw->input->user_agent();

    $data['LOG_USER_ID'] = $_fw->session->userdata('USER_ID') != null?$_fw->session->userdata('USER_ID'):0;

    $data['LOG_ADDEN_ON'] = mktime();

    $data['OPERATION_IP'] = $_fw->input->ip_address();

    $sql = $_fw->db->query("CALL dpe_acl.pkg_SYSTEM_LOGS.addSystemLogs('', '".$data['LOG_TYPE']."', '".$data['LOG_URI_STRING']."', '".$data['LOG_MESSAGE']."', '".$data['LOG_DESCRIPTION']."', '".$data['LOG_USER_AGENT']."', '".$data['LOG_USER_ID']."', '".$data['LOG_ADDEN_ON']."', '".$data['OPERATION_IP']."')");

    return;
}
```

doing this I am getting a warning like this

```
Severity: Warning

Message: oci_fetch_assoc(): ORA-24374: define not done before fetch or execute and fetch

Filename: oci8/oci8_result.php

Line Number: 83
```

Please help... Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs because you have not bound the in/out parameters correctly before calling the stored procedure. Now I ave not a lot of experience with CI so I don't know how it executes the query string, but I do know that you have to bind the input and output parameters to local variables first, you can't just put them in the query string.

Here is a link to an example that may help you figure this out.  http://www.dbmotive.com/ora-24374-define-not-done-before-fetch-or-execute-and-fetch/

Answer (score 0):

for store procedure use `$this->db->stored_procedure('package or schema','you_store_procedure',$parameters)`.
the $parameters is like this:

```
$parametros=array( 
   array('name'=>':param','value'=>'pass_variable or value','length'=>-1,'type'=>SQLT_CHR),
   array('name'=>':param','value'=>'pass_variable or value','length'=>-1,'type'=>SQLT_CHR), ....
);
```

> For OUT params, preceded the variable with & and set length value , example 
>      `array('name'=>':param','value'=>&$param,'length'=>30,'type'=>SQLT_CHR)`

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your model :

```
if (!$this->db) {
  $m = oci_error();
  trigger_error(htmlentities($m['message']), E_USER_ERROR);
}

$stid = oci_parse($this->db->conn_id, 'BEGIN PROCEDURE_NAME(:PARAMETER_1,:PARAMETER_2,:OUT_MESSAGE); end;');

oci_bind_by_name($stid, ':PARAMAETER_1',  $PARAMAETER_1,200);
oci_bind_by_name($stid, ':PARAMETER_2',  $PARAMETER_2,200);
oci_bind_by_name($stid, ':OUT_MESSAGE',  $OUT_MESSAGE ,100, SQLT_CHR);

if(oci_execute($stid)){
  $results = $OUT_MESSAGE;
}
oci_free_statement($stid);
oci_close($this->db->conn_id);

return  $results;
```