# How to call an oracle stored procedure having in and out parameter using codeigniter?

Tags: php, oracle, codeigniter, oci8

I already setup the codeigniter dbdriver to "oci8".

For reference, here's my stored procedure. This is just my sample stored procedure.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE STORED PROCEDURE sp_sample(
in_id IN VARCHAR2, 
out_code OUT varchar, 
out_desc OUT varchar) IS

var_result VARCHAR2(100);

CURSOR GetStatus (my_id IN NUMBER) IS
SELECT status
FROM tbl_sample
WHERE id= my_id;

BEGIN
     OPEN GetStatus(in_id);
           LOOP
     FETCH GetStatus into var_result;
     EXIT WHEN GetStatus%NOTFOUND;
           END LOOP;
     CLOSE GetStatus;

     IF(result != 'A')
          UPDATE tbl_sample SET status = 'A'
          WHERE id = in_id;

          COMMIT;

          out_code := '00';
          out_desc := 'Success';
     ELSE
          out_code := '01';
          out_desc := 'Already active';
     END IF;
END sp_sample;
```

And this is how I call the stored proc in codeigniter:

```
$id = '10';
$params = array($id);
$result = $this->db->query("CALL sp_sample(?, @out_code, @out_desc)", $params);

exit($result);
```

Then I get this error message:

```
Query error: ORA-00936: missing expression - Invalid query: CALL sp_sample('10', @out_code, @out_code)
```

My question now is how can I call the oracle stored procedure using codeigniter? How to bind the parameters correctly?

Thanks,
Irvin

Comment: check from here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29033762/how-to-call-oracle-stored-procedure-in-codeigniter

Comment: I already done that, but I get an error of:
`
ORA-01008: not all variables bound - Invalid query: CALL sp_sample('10481', :out_code, :out_desc)
`

Here's my code:

`
$params = "'{$id}', :out_code, :out_desc";
  $bindvar = array(
   array("name" => ":out_code", "value" => "", "type" => SQLT_CHR, "length" => -1),
   array("name" => ":out_desc", "value" => "", "type" => SQLT_CHR, "length" => -1)
  );
  $result = $this->db->query("CALL sp_sample($params)", $bindvar)->result();

  exit(print_r($result, true));
`